# Build Amazon AMI from virtualbox

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, amazon-ami, packer

Just would like to know how can I build an Amazon AMI from ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04 machine.
Also would like to know after creating an AMI how can I upload to Amazon and use the same.

Would be great to know if we anyone has done it prior to this.

Thanks

Chand Prakash

Comment: The fact you want to do this points to some red flags- why can't you build Ubuntu from a list of tasks, rather than trying to freeze a development machine?

Comment: Actually I deploy lots of openedx machines and its like everytime we deploy a new one it has different issues its like highly system binded platform. So this would be basically a time saving thing if we made a deployment we can directly have an AMI built and deploy that to client accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need **packer**.

> Packer is a tool for creating identical machine images for multiple platforms from a single source configuration. "Packer is a modern tool that embraces best benefits. It's completely automated, simply run a a packer build, no human touches it, packer builds it for you. " - Mitchell Hashimoto (Creator)

We build AMI images via packer template and it is really good and simplify the whole processes.

If you need know more about packer and how it works, please refer: http://packer.io

If you need a quick start from samples, you can go through this github  repo:

[shiguredo/packer-templates](https://github.com/shiguredo/packer-templates)